# What has changed since the Messiah Complex?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

I've identified the Messiah complex as the latest X-Men Comic book arc that I'm familiar with, and I'd like to know the major points that have changed X-men/marvel history since then (with the aim of buying the TPBs to fill the gaps in my knowledge). Wikipedia have a listing of all of the preceding story lines since Messia Complex:

- "Divided We Stand"
- "Manifest Destiny"
- "X-Infernus"
- "Messiah War"
- "Utopia"
- "Nation X"
- "Necrosha"
- "Second Coming"
- "Curse of the Mutants"
- "Age of X"
- "Schism"
- "Regenesis"

But I can't tell from these entries which of these has featured the largest change in the world of Marvel.

Now I know this might come down to being subjective, but my main interest in this question is the ***relevance*** of the story arc, which one story since the Messia Complex, has had the most impact on the X-men/Marvel *still felt "today"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of all these storylines, I believe (as the owner of a comic book store) that the two most important follow-ups are "Second Coming" and "Schism".

"Second Coming" shows how Cable returns from the future to return Hope (the mutant Messiah) to her proper timeline.  The X-Men fight to protect her, and Nightcrawler sacrifies himself in a battle with Bastion.  This story arc was published as 13 chapters across the various X-titles, and each chapter was instrumental (not just spin-off stories/adventures).

"Schism" shows how the team splits into two factions: Cyclops' team stays on Utopia, while Wolverine's team restarts the school in Westchester.  The impact of the story is that there are now two distinct X-Men teams in "Uncanny X-Men" and "Wolverine & the X-Men", respectively.

Of course, "Avengers vs. X-Men" is the current storyline that should prove to be extremely significant to the makeup of the entire Marvel superhero universe.